# Were Any of the Aircraft in "Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow" Based on Real Planes?

Tags: sky-captain-world-of-tomorrow

In *Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow*, we see a number of planes used when the robots raid the city, but later we also see Sky Captain's headquarters, consisting of an airfield and at least one large hanger.

Are any of the aircraft Sky Captain used based on actual planes or lighter than air craft, or are they all fictional designs?

Comment: Not quite germane, but the giant robots were based on the eponymous Mechanical Monsters from the Fleischer Superman cartoon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Sky Captain's plane was based on heavily modified P-40 Warhawk (I think it was more precisely a P-40N [Kittyhawk](https://web.archive.org/web/20120331221750/http://nzwarbirds.org.nz/p40a.html)).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0346156/trivia):

> Sky Captain flies a late-model P-40, the six gun version of the P-40N. However, his has a few "Hollywoodifications":
>
> - The rear decking behind the pilot's seat, and the fuselage fuel tank under it, were removed in order to add a second seat (for Polly). This was actually done to some real P-40s for flight instruction.
> - The pop-open bays for the cable launcher and magnet bombs are right in the middle of the centerline fuel tank (which fills the interior of the wing between the main wheel wells).
> - The small underwater engines under the horizontal stabilizers would retract right into the tail wheel gear well, and into each other.
> - When going into underwater mode, the ostensibly solid-metal propeller blades collapse down into the prop spinner, and into a different section of space-time. The real plane's prop spinner is a shell that goes around the collars and gearing of the prop hub assembly.
> - Roughly 5000 horsepower appears to have been added to the 1200hp Allison engine.

Sky Captain's P-40N:

[image: plane as seen in the movie]

Real Kittyhawk ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20160408080603/http://www.touchdown-aviation.com/flying-legends/plane/amicale-jean-baptiste-salis/curtiss-p-40n-kittyhawk-f-azku.php)):

[image: plane flying]

[image: plane on land]

Comment: There were a number of other real world WWII era aircraft which made some appearances as well, though mostly as background.

Comment: @BBlake - possible. But it's an "any" question, so 1 example is more than enough :)

Comment: Personally I'm a little disappointed they used a P40 on place of the much more capable and interesting P51 Mustang or the F4u Corsair

Comment: @StormeHawke - Including aircraft that appeared mid-WWII at a point before WWII began would mean Sky Captain (or, rather his chief engineer) had generous access to Time Travel technology, surely?!?

Comment: And the planes of the evil faction somewhat resembled the Horten Ho 229 (although it just might be that all flying wings tend to look a bit similar), except that the Ho 229 did not flap its wings.

Answer (score 3):

At one point in the movie there were several large aircraft on the ramp that looked to be some variant of B-24 "Liberator" as well, although we never see them in the air.

Also, the aircraft on the RAF's flying airfield look to be based on the Bell XP-55 "Ascender," a 1943 experimental aircraft that never went into production.